How can I verify if the user is logged in, when the call is from a client side component?
In my Next js 14+ app I have a Client side component Search component as below
"use client"
// ...
// import { headers } from "next/headers"

const SearchName = ({setSelectedUser}) => {
    //...

  // Function to fetch users from the database
  const fetchUsers = async (searchTerm) => {
    if(searchTerm){
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          // const headersList = headers();
          // const cookie = headersList.get('cookie');
          const response = await fetch(`/api/users?search=${searchTerm}`, {
            method: "GET",
            // headers: {
            //   'Cookie': cookie
            // }
            // headers: headers()
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            credentials: "include",
          });
          if (response.status === 401) {
            // Redirect to login if unauthorized
            router.push("/login");
            return;
          } else {
          const data = await response.json();

          setResults(data); // Set the fetched users as results
        }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
        }
    
        setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Search Input Field */}
      <form className="mb-6">
        <div className="relative">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search by email"
            value={query}
            onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            className="w-full pl-10 pr-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-transparent"
          />
          <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center pointer-events-none">
            <Search className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>      

      {/* Display loading state */}
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}

      {/* Display search results */}
      <div>
        <ul className="space-y-3">
          {Array.isArray(results) && results?.map((user) => (
            <li key={user._id}>
              <button
                onClick={() => handleUserClick(user)}
                className="w-full flex items-center p-3 hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-md transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
              >
                <span className="ml-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">{user.email}</span>
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>      
    </div>
  );

};
export default SearchName;

I have an API route defined as follows:
// app/api/users/route.js
import User from "@/models/User";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";

export async function GET(req) {
    // Check if the session is active
    const session = await getServerSession({ req, ...authOptions });

    if (!session) {
      return new Response(
        JSON.stringify({ error: "Unauthorized. Please log in." }),
        {
          status: 401,
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }
      );
    }
    //...
}

When a call is made to the API route I would like to check if the user is logged in.
However the getServerSession(...) function always returns null.
How can i check if the user is logged in in an API route when the call is from a Client Side component?
I went through this and
tried setting cookies in the fetch request but could not as it is a Client Side component - see the commented code in the fetch statement above...

try passing authOptions like this getServerSession(authOptions).I get session info using this way.

Get session info on Server Side:
api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
import authOptions from '@/lib/options'
import NextAuth from "next-auth"

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }


Extracted auth options to separate file options.ts
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
    }),
    // other providers
  ]
};

export default authOptions;

now you can access user session in server side
const session = getServerSession(authOptions);

Example usage: I have created a method which to access user id in various api endpoints
import authOptions from "@/lib/options";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

export async function getUserId() {
    try {
        const user = (await getServerSession(authOptions))?.user;
        const currentUserId  = user?.id;
    
        return { current_userId: currentUserId || null };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('getUserId() ',error.message)
        return { current_userId:null, error: error.message };
    }
}

Get Session info on Client Side:
use useSession hook on client side to get session info.
But to use this hook your components must be wrapped with SessionProvider.
export const RootComponent = ({ children, session }) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>

        {children}

    </SessionProvider>
  );
};

and use session hook in components
  const {data:session, status } = useSession();


Yes i tried that first but the session still came back as null. Maybe something else. The question is about getting the session on the server when a client side component makes a call.

then use getServerSession(authOptions); instead of passing it as destructured with req. I tried your syntax and it throws error or returns null. I am passing authOptions directly as single param and it works. I will update the answer to include the example
